# ceph-deploy install --release fails to upgrade on debian stretch

Tags: debian-stretch, ceph

this is my first post on serverfault!

I'm trying to setup a test ceph cluster to see if it can meet our storage needs.

I've been following the instructions [here](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-deploy-ceph-storage-cluster-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/)

I ran into some permissions issues when deploying the mgr.  Turns out debian was deploying v 10.x, so I fixed this by:

```
ceph-deploy install --release luminous <mon_node>
```

luminous worked fine but any other version just does nothing!  If I try:

```
ceph-deploy install --release octopus <mon_node>
```

It just goes through the process and ends up with luminous still.

I'm considering starting over and folowing [this](https://ralph.blog.imixs.com/2020/04/14/ceph-octopus-running-on-debian-buster/)
This uses the newer cephadm cmd

But curious if anyone else has experienced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hi so I figured this out, I changed to buster, then ran on all the nodes and I have nautilus installed now.  Strange the ceph-deploy release doesn't work, good thing this is just a test cluster cause in production I would want to be able to upgrade, or I guess wait for debian to add to backports.

```
apt-get -t buster-backports install ceph
```